# Javascript - Encontrar palabras parecidas en un Array()

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo el siguiente Array()

```
palabras = ["anatomia","ana","angie","anatómico","anatómica","análisis","analogía","analizar","anabólico"];
```

Ahora bien, en HTML tengo:

```
<!-- Qué complicado, oh mi Dios -->
<input type="text" name="palabra" class="p">
```

Para capturar el value del input tengo:

```
$(".p").on('input', function(event) {
    if ($.inArray($(this).val(), palabras);) {
        console.log("Reached!!");
    }else{
        console.log("Waiting / You're typing...");
    }
});
```

Quisiera poder capturar la palabra sin necesidad de escribirla completa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pues lo que tengo solo captura si la palabra está completa en el input :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma de resolver este problema, es "*limpiando*" (`normalizar`) las palabras, es decir, quitar los caracteres con acentos.

Pasos a realizar:

1. Normalizar el arreglo de palabras.
2. Ordenar alfabéticamente el arreglo normalizado.
3. Detectar la entrada de un valor y normalizar el mismo.
4. Buscar el valor ingresado en el arreglo de palabras normalizadas.

Aquí te dejo una posible solución.

```js
$(function(){
  function normalizeWord(word) {
    var letters = [{
        search: 'áäàãâ',
        replace: 'a'
      }, {
        search: 'éëèê',
        replace: 'e'
      }, {
        search: 'íïìî',
        replace: 'i'
      }, {
       search: 'óöòõô',
       replace: 'o'
      }, {
        search: 'úüùû',
        replace: 'u'
      }, {
        search: 'ñ',
        replace: 'n'
      }, {
        search: 'ç',
        replace: 'c'
      }],
      normal;
    
    // Convertimos la palabra a minusculas
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    normal = word;

    // Por cada "letra"
    $.each(letters, function(idx, letter) {
      var re = new RegExp('[' + letter.search + ']', 'g');
      // Reemplazamos el caracter acentuado
      normal = normal.replace(re, letter.replace);
    });
  
    // Devolvemos un objeto con la palabra original y la normalizada
    return {
      original: word,
      normal: normal
    };
  }
  
  function normalizeWords(words) {
    var response = [];
  
    // Por cada palabra
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      // Obtenemos la palabra normlalizada
      response.push(normalizeWord(word));
    });
  
    return response;
  }
  
  function sortNormalizedWords(a, b) {
    if (a.normal > b.normal) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.normal < b.normal) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  function sortShortWords(a, b) {
    if (a.length > b.length) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.length < b.length) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  
  //

   var palabras = ["anatomia","Ana","angie","anatómico","anatómica","análisis","analogía","analizar","anabólico","Analuz", "tu", "tú", "túnel"],
       // Obtenemos la palabras normalizadas (sin caracteres acentuados)
       words = normalizeWords(palabras);
  
  // Ordenamos el arreglo de la A a la Z
  words.sort(sortNormalizedWords);
  
  $( "#entrada").on('input', function() {
    var key = this.value,
        posibles = [],
        lucky = false;
    
    // Normalizamos el valor ingresado
    key = normalizeWord(key);
    
    // Por cada palabra
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      // Validamos que contenga el valor ingresado
      if (word.normal.indexOf(key.normal) !== -1) {
        posibles.push(word.original);
        
        // Si es exactamente la palabra buscada
        if (key.original === word.original) {
          lucky = word.original;
        }
        // Si es igual a la palabras normalizada
        else if (!lucky && key.normal === word.normal) {
          lucky = word.normal;
        }
      }
    });
    
    // Imprimimos todas las palabras que contienen el valor ingresado
    $('#posibles').val(posibles.join(','));
    
    // Si no encontramos la pablabra exacta, 
    // ordenamos el arreglo de posibles
    // y devolvemos la primera
    if (!lucky) {
      lucky = posibles.sort(sortShortWords)[0];
     }
    $('#acertada').val(lucky);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Entrada:
<input type="text" id="entrada"><br>
Posibles:
<input type="text" id="posibles" readonly><br>
Mas acertada:
<input type="text" id="acertada" readonly><br>
```

Comment: El código trabaja de forma impresionante. Mi pregunta es, si quisiera que como máximo hayan 3 sugerencias, y que cada sugerencia esté en un div, de qué forma podría hacerlo?

Comment: Ya lo conseguí :) No te preocupes

Comment: Respecto a las revisiones hechas, hay problemas usando "tú" y "tu" en el Array() **Palabras**

Comment: Si escribes **tú** en el input principal, **la más acertada** es **tu** cuando debería ser igualmente **tú**

Comment: Escribe **Tú**, y verás que sólo arrojará **tu**

Comment: Cuando no se pone nada en el input este arroja todas las posibles soluciones?

Comment: @Cig, puedes ejecutar el `script` y ver que si. En la pregunta, en ningún momento se indica lo contrario. Agregar una condición para validar el largo mínimo del valor ingresado es algo muy simple de hacer.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Gracias, es que tu solución me ayudo a un problema que tenía. Gracias

Comment: Cuando escribo **Tú** (Notese la inicial en mayúscula), devueve **tú** (Notese la inicial en minuscula). Como puedo hacer que devuelva **Tú** igualmente.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz, **Tú** no esta en el arreglo de opciones, en cambio **tú** si, por lo que seria incorrecto devolver **Tú**

Comment: Existe una forma con Expresiones Regulares?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz, mi solución usa expresiones regulares...

Comment: Para la situación que te acabo de comunicar, me refiero.

Answer (score 4):

```js
palabras = ["anatomia","ana","angie","anatómico","anatómica","análisis","analogía","analizar","anabólico"];

//Autocomplete funciona para completar palabras
$( ".p" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: palabras,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />

<!-- tu input -->
<input type="text" name="palabra" class="p">
```

Toda la documentación en [Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: +1 por ser el primer intento de respuesta. Aún no he probado tu código, lo haré más tarde.

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta me ha interesado bastante por esa razón he diseñado un auto-completador sencillo y espero que mi respuesta sea util para tu problema, Veamos el codigo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var $input = $('.in');
  var $proof = $('.proof');

  // Tu arreglo de palabras
  var arr = [
    'ana',
    'angie',
    'anatomica',
    'analogo',
    'analizar',
    'analisis',
    'analogia',
    'anatomia',
  ];

  $input.on('input', handler);

  // Callback
  function handler (e) {

    $proof.empty();
    var data = $(this).val();

    /* Primero que todo ... */
    if (data !== '') {

      /**
       * La palabra justamente debe ser igual a alguna del arreglo.
       * Si no se debera encontrar alguna coincidencia con la palabra
       * ingresada.
       */
      if (arr.indexOf(data) !== -1) {
        $proof.append('la palabra es: ' + arr[arr.indexOf(data)]);
      } else {

        /**
         * Arreglo `arrDiffLength` almacenara la diferencia
         * entre la/s palabra/s del arreglo 'arr' con la palabra
         * ingresada por ejemplo:
         *    'analisis'.length - 'ana'.length === 5
         */
        var arrDiffLength = [];

        /**
         * Arreglo `arrShortWord` almacenara la/s palabra/s ajustadas
         * al tamaño de la palabra ingresada, es decir, 'analogo' ajustada
         * al tamaño de 'anali' seria 'analo' de esta forma se logra encontrar
         * si la palabra coincide parcialmente con una palabra del arreglo.
         */
        var arrShortWord = [];

        // Variable a utilizar para concatenar las palabras ajustadas.
        var temp = '';

        // Iteracion para encontrar la/s diferencia/s.
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          arrDiffLength.push(arr[i].length - data.length);
        }

        // Iteracion para encontrar las palabras ajustadas.
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            temp += arr[i][j];
          }
          arrShortWord.push(temp);
          temp = '';
        }

        /**
         * Valor minimo del arreglo `arrDiffLength`.
         * Se utilizara para encontrar la palabra mas corta
         * que coincida con la palabra ingresada.
         */
        var minVal = Math.min.apply(null, arrDiffLength);

        // Indice del valor minimo en el arreglo `arrShortWord`
        var indexOfMinVal = arrDiffLength.indexOf(minVal);

        /**
         * Condicional para verificar que almenos una o mas
         * coincidencias existen entre el arreglo `arrShortWord`
         * y la palabra ingresada.
         */
        if (arrShortWord.indexOf(data) !== -1) {
          /**
           * Se busca la palabra que coincida con la palabra ingresada
           * y que sea la mas pequeña.
           * Si no, se itera para encontrar otras coincidencias.
           */
          if (arrShortWord[indexOfMinVal] === data) {
            $proof.append('La palabra es: ', arr[indexOfMinVal]);
          } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              if (arrShortWord[i] === data) {
                $proof.append('La palabra es: ', arr[i]);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          $proof.append('La palabra no se encuentra.');
        }
      }
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Auto comletador</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Simple input -->
    <input class="in" type="text">

    <!-- Aqui se mostrara la palabra acertada -->
    <div class="proof"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Lo he diseñado según tus criterios en la pregunta y he comentado el codigo para que puedas entenderlo rapidamente, espero que sea de ayuda Saludos!.