# ¿Se puede buscar en javascript con .startsWith omitiendo tildes?

Tags: javascript, filtro

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente función para buscar un término introducido en un buscador.

Busco un valor dentro de un array, en una posición en concreto del array para comprobar si existe.

```
/***** BUSCAR EN EL ARRAY PRODUCTOS POR VALOR Y POSICION ****/
function buscar(mi_array, valor, pos){
    count = 0;
    var results = mi_array.filter(function (mi_array) { return (mi_array[pos].toUpperCase().startsWith(valor.toUpperCase())) && count++ < 36; }); 
    var firstObj = (results.length > 0) ? results[0] : null;
    return results;

}
```

Mi problema viene cuando el usuario busca un producto con tilde y en el array donde busca la función está sin tilde y viceversa.

¿Cómo podría tratar este problema?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Javascript - Encontrar palabras parecidas en un Array()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37788/javascript-encontrar-palabras-parecidas-en-un-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta sustituir en el return el startWith(...) por el siguiente:

```
startsWith(valor.toUpperCase()
.replace("Á","A")
.replace("É","E")
.replace("Í","I")
.replace("Ó","O")
.replace("Ú","U")
.replace("Ü","U"))
```

Debería funcionar ya que convierte todas las vocales con acento o las ü en sus respectivas vocales.

Comment: exacto, trata de eliminar los caracteres especiales como indica @kmevi10 y comparar siempre (salvo que necesites una solución case sensitive) convirtiendo las cadenas en minúsculas o mayúsculas para evitar dolores de cabeza innecesarios

Comment: Casi! Con esa solución se consigue que si el usuario escribe con tilde, se la quita. El problema viene cuando el usuario escribe con tilde y el array donde busca también tiene tilde, al quitarla en el primer proceso ya no la encuentra. Otro problema es que el usuario escriba sin tilde y el array donde busca si la tenga, entonces intenta reemplazar (para nada) y sigue sin encontrarlo al tener tilde el array.

Comment: Se podría solucionar ambos problemas si también pudiese convertir todos los registros del array a sin tilde. Es viable escribir mi_array[pos].toUpperCase( <-- Escribir aqui todos los replaces anteriores también --> ) ???

Comment: Pues si, edito tu solución agregando lo que te he comentado y queda perfecta!